# Floating Point - Regular expression

Tags: regex, qt

I am struggling to understand this simple regular expression. I have the following attempt:

```
[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*
```

I understand this as zero-to-many numeric digits, followed by one-to-zero periods and finally ending in zero-to-many numeric digits.

I am not want to match anything other than exactly as above. I do not want positive/negative support or any other special support types. However, for some reason, the above also matches what appear to be random characters. All of the following for whatever reason match:

- f32
- 32a
- 32-
- =33

In an answer, I am looking for:

- An explanation of why my regular expression does not work.
- A working version with an explanation of why it does work.

**Edit**: Due to what seems to be causing trouble, I have added the "QT" tag, that is the environment I am working with.

**Edit**: Due to continued confusion, I am going to add a bit of code. I am starting to think I am either misusing QT, or QT has a problem:

```
void subclassedQDialog::setupTxtFilters()
{
    QRegExp numbers("^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$");
    txtToFilter->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(numbers,this));
}
```

This is from within a subclassed QDialog. txtToFilter is a QLineEdit. I can provide more code if someone can suggest what may be relevant. While the expression above is not the original, it is one of the ones from comments below and also fails in the same way.

Comment: Could you please show the code that you use to test matching?

Comment: Language? Do you want the number to be alone on the line? Some answers seem to assume that.

Comment: I am using QT and a QRegExpValidator (http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qregexpvalidator.html) I was hoping this wouldn't be the issue :\

Comment: The numbers will be alone, but I am using QT, which uses the expression as a filter. Basically, it is supposed to lock you out from adding anything contradictory to the expression.

Comment: Thank you everyone, for historic purposes I have done +1 for each current answer which answers the base problem of the regular expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is you haven't escaped the \ properly, you need to put \\. Otherwise the C++ compiler will strip out the \ (at least gcc does this, with a warning) and the regex engine will treat the . as any character.

Comment: Sigh, so deep in these expressions that I forget the basics. I swear these expressions are too confusing. Thank you!

Comment: Backslashes in regexes are really confusing when writing them as strings in a language that uses backslashes inside strings anyway.  It is a fact of life - until someone creates a regex system that avoids using backslashes to escape things inside a regex (but that isn't likely to happen either).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler long live C# literal strings!

Answer (score 1):

Put `^` at the start and `$` at the end. This anchors your regex to the start and end of the string.

Comment: While this may be true (I don't know), my environment seems to take care of this for me, no difference is made.

Comment: @Serodis Perhaps it's a good time to tell us about your environment then :)

Answer (score 1):

Your expression find a match in the middle of the string. If you add anchors to the beginning and to the end of your expression, the strings from your list will be ignored. Your expression would match empty strings, but that't the price you pay for being able to match `.99` and `99.` strings.

```
^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$
```

A better choice would be

```
^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?$
```

because it would match the decimal point only if at least one digit is present after it.

Answer (score 1):

One of them needs to be a `+` instead of `*`. Do you want to allow "`.9`" to be valid, or will you require the leading `0`?

Comment: I don't care if there is a preceding 0 or not. I am okay with .9 and okay with 0.9

Comment: Then you may need to split it out - a case for an integer and a case for a floating point with optional leading integer. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html for the answer of "`[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+`"

Comment: I have tried changing the first numeric-group to a +. While that disables the letter in the front, it is allowed after the first digit.

Comment: With your clarifications, I still don't see how the expression doesn't always pass because a null string is "valid" as it is written.

Comment: Well, for example 'AA' does not pass.